# File permissions restore in Git

Tags: git, file, permissions, hook, executable

The following is the requirement:

1. Create a file test.sql , set the  permissions to **–rwxr-xr--** i.e here 
   the owner and groups has executable. Let's say the file is pushed to 
   source control
2. When I want to download the file back from source control the 
   permissions should be retained as it is **- –rwxr-xr--**.

With Git when I pull the file from repository I see the permissions 
–rwxr-xr-x i.e the others have executable permissions which I wouldn't 
require.

The permissions should also be retained in development.

Could you please let me know how to retain the permissions when archiving.
I saw several answers in the forum but I couldn't get which one should be implemented,
git hooks? scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/andris9/1978266).

You store the permissions of your files and directories in a separate file named `.git_cache_meta` and no directly under git.

A full sample can be found [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/105133%7C%7CPATCH)

Copied form the above post:

```
+# git bundle create mybundle.bdl master; git-cache-meta --store
+# scp mybundle.bdl .git_cache_meta machine2: #then on machine2:
+# git init; git pull mybundle.bdl master; git-cache-meta --apply
```